# Install android on an windows tablet

Tags: installation

I got an old TrekStor SurfTab Duo W1 with an Intel Atom x5-Z8300 (x86) processor and want to install andoid on it. But I got a problem in finding the correct android version. Till now it crashes every time I start it.

Comment: Have you tried Android-x86?

Comment: @Robert Are there specific versions for every processor or just one for x86, armv or so?

Comment: `Android-x86` is the name of the project: https://www.android-x86.org/

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out. :)

Comment: @Robert When trying to boot android x86 I'm stuck at the screen "Detecting Android-x86... found at /dev/..." waiting over 30min. Nothing happened.

Comment: Well Android-x86 is an open source project. Nobody claims that it works on every hardware. May be you have to try out an older version or adapt something. For questions on Android-x86 you better go here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-x86

Comment: @Robert Thank you. :)